# How sql server store a new column on data page?

Tags: sql-server, database, memory-management

I've added a new column to my table (after rows inserted in it). I want to know if this column store on the same data page that row stored or different page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the normal columns are in the same 8k page, the exception are columns storing large data like `varchar(max)`

Comment: even the columns added after row inserted?

Comment: Yes, all the columns. When the column is added, it's a metadata operation, it's not physically added there until you update a value into it.